# Launching exetrnal cmd.exe file and passing parameters to it using subprocess python

Tags: python

i am trying to launch external cmd.exe file(atmelstudio.exe file) and pass arguments to it. but when i run the script using subprocees.call(,args), i can only see atmelstudio.exe popping out without any passed parameters.

```
subprocess.call([atmel_cmd, 'atprogram'])
```

this is the command window pop up after exceuting the above line:

[image]

please suggest how to pass arguments to this application using python.

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. Copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: You will have to pass parameters into your subprocess.call

Comment: It seems you are doing everything right. Passing arguments in the list you give as the first argument to subprocess.call. Are you sure that the parameters don't arrive at the programm? Your command line output suggests that it recieved the name "atprogram".

Comment: it didn't receive the argument, its displaying the message saying use 'atprogram' fro programming.still unable to pass the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see atprogram needs additional arguments.

```
Usage: atprogram [options] <command> [arguments] [<command> [arguments] ...]
```

I would tried atprogram help to see whether the arguments are passed or not.

```
subprocess.call([atmel_cmd, 'atprogram' , 'help'])
```

I assume that atmel_cmd is also a string.
Rather than that the call itself looks alright.

Here [atprogramm documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00002466A.pdf#page=7)  for further reference.

Comment: i m still facing the same issue,'atmel_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Extensions\Application\StudioCommandPrompt.exe".its not taking the arguments passed. in this case 'atprogram,'help'.please suggest